# Dynamic argument in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

this is my docker file, I'd like to pass a dynamic value to this URL based on the system architecture using uname-m in this URL.
In the URL where it says amd64, I would like to pass the current system architecture like arch64 or arm64.
I am trying how to retrieve and pass it using uname-m

curl -SLO [https://xxxxx.com/xx/v${LND_VERSION}/lnd-linux-amd64-v${LND_VERSION}.tar.gz/v${LND_VERSION}/lnd-linux-**amd64**-v${LND_VERSION}.tar.gz](https://xxxxx.com/xx/v$%7BLND_VERSION%7D/lnd-linux-amd64-v$%7BLND_VERSION%7D.tar.gz/v$%7BLND_VERSION%7D/lnd-linux-**amd64**-v$%7BLND_VERSION%7D.tar.gz)

```
FROM debian:stable-slim
        
        ARG LND_VERSION
        
        RUN uname-m
        
        ENV PATH=/opt/lnd-linux-amd64-v${LND_VERSION}:$PATH
     
        
        RUN curl -SLO https://xxxxx.com/xx/v${LND_VERSION}/lnd-linux-amd64-v${LND_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && tar -xzf *.tar.gz -C /opt \
  && rm *.tar.gz

        COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

        RUN chmod a+x /entrypoint.sh

        ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

        CMD ["lnd"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --print-architecture` returns the architecture, so you should be able to get it using

```
RUN curl -SLO https://xxxxx.com/xx/v${LND_VERSION}/lnd-linux-$(dpkg --print-architecture)-v${LND_VERSION}.tar.gz
```